# Another exception was thrown: Expected a value of type 'Widget', but got one of type '_Future<dynamic>( Flutter-Dart )

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I tried to put the ChatAsServer() class in an asynchronous function and return the class, but it throws this error :

*Another exception was thrown: Expected a value of type 'Widget', but got one of type '_Future'*

how to fix it ?
Please tell me, I will be grateful !

I have a function CreateServer() to create a server and return the class with widget.
This my code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project_hotspot_messenger/msgs.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

var jist = <IOWebSocketChannel>[];

class ChatAsServer extends StatefulWidget {
  IOWebSocketChannel channel;
  ChatAsServer({super.key, required this.channel});

  @override
  State<ChatAsServer> createState() => _ChatAsServerState(channel: channel);
}

class _ChatAsServerState extends State<ChatAsServer> {
  IOWebSocketChannel channel;
  _ChatAsServerState({required this.channel});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double widthek = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final TextEditingController _sms_controller = new TextEditingController();
    double heightek = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leadingWidth: 30,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: Navigator.of(context).pop,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new),
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        title: TextButton(
          autofocus: true,
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'Chat (as server)',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "Last on ${DateTime.now()}",
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: channel.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  // return mess(snapshot.data, widthek);
                  messages.add(mess(snapshot.data, widthek, false));
                  return ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: messages.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return messages[index];
                    },
                  );
                }),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Container(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, top: 10.0),
              height: 60.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onEditingComplete: () {
                        _sms_controller.text = "";
                      },
                      controller: _sms_controller,
                      //controller:_controller,
                      // focusNode: _focus_sms,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 8.0, bottom: 12.0, top: 12.0),
                          isDense: true,
                          hintText: 'Сообщение',
                          hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                            height: 1.0,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      // channel.sink.add(_sms_controller.text);
                      messages.add(mess(_sms_controller.text, widthek, true));
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.send),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    iconSize: 40.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

CreateServer() async {
  final server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 4747);
  await for (HttpRequest request in server) {
    final channel =
        IOWebSocketChannel(await WebSocketTransformer.upgrade(request));
    channel;
    return ChatAsServer(channel: channel);
  }
}
```